# pandas: apply filters taking into account timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I have the following test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'date': ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-07'],
     'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5], 'name': ['Darren', 'Sabrina', 'Steve', 'Sean', 'Ray', 'Stef', 'Dany']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

The question is: Going back in time x days (viewed from every single entry), are there more than y distinct names which share the same id?

Here is the code I have written. In my example I go back x=2 days and check for at least two distinct names (y=1) sharing the same id. If at least two distinct names exist, I save 1 inside the list "result_store", otherwise 0. Of course, in this example, going back x days is not possible if i is smaller x, but this little inaccuracy is not a problem for me.

```
def rule(data, x=2, y=1):
    result_store = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        id = data['id'][i]
        end_time = data['date'][i]
        start_time = end_time-datetime.timedelta(days=x)
        time_frame = data[(data['date'] >= start_time) & (data['date'] <= end_time)]
        time_frame = time_frame.loc[time_frame['id'] == id]
        distinct_names = time_frame['name'].nunique()
        if distinct_names > y:
            result_store.append(1)
        else:
            result_store.append(0)

    return result_store
```

The result is

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

In reality, I have thousands of rows and my solution is extremely slow. I have also tried to parallelize over the index i using parmap, but the speedup also is not satisfactory. Is there any more efficient way to do this? Maybe by using pyspark?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for **spark2.4**(`array_distinct` only in **2.4**). I used the **DataFrame** you provided, and **spark inferred** the column date to be of type `TimestampType`. For my spark code to work, the column date **has to be of type `TimestampType`**. The `window` function travels back 2 days, based on **same id**, and collects a list of names. If the number of **distinct names** are >1, then it inputs 1, otherwise 0.

The code below uses `rangeBetween(-(86400*2),Window.currentRow)` which basically means that to include **currentRow** and then go back **2 days**, so if current **row date is 3, it will include** `[3,2,1]`. if you only want current row date and 1 day before, you could replace `86400*2` with `86400*1`

```
#If you can't use spark2.4 or get stuck, please leave a comment. 



from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df=spark.createDataFrame(data)

w=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy((F.col("date")).cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(86400*2),Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("no_distinct", F.size(F.array_distinct(F.collect_list("name").over(w))))\
  .withColumn("no_distinct", F.when(F.col("no_distinct")>1, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .orderBy(F.col("date")).show()

+-------------------+---+-------+-----------+
|               date| id|   name|no_distinct|
+-------------------+---+-------+-----------+
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|  1| Darren|          0|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|  2|Sabrina|          0|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|  2|  Steve|          1|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|  3|   Sean|          0|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|  4|    Ray|          0|
|2014-01-06 00:00:00|  4|   Stef|          1|
|2014-01-07 00:00:00|  5|   Dany|          0|
+-------------------+---+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response! At the moment I am trying to get pyspark up and running and I have a few problems: "Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" Tomorrow I will meet a colleague in order to fix the problems.